Limit the dropdown to logged in user for a table field
My tables are:
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
    on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    primary_key=True,
    )
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)

class ProfileCar(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_model = models.ForeignKey(CarModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class AvailableRide(models.Model):  
    profilecar = models.ForeignKey(ProfileCar,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ride_route = models.ForeignKey(Route,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ride_datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

In AvailableRide table, when running it, it shows the complete list of profilecar values, meaning all the users get listed. I want to limit this list to only logged in user.
The list needs to be limited to logged in user only, who has onetoone profile record.
